# Kubuntu solution for analysing/recording streamed flash audio?

Tags: audio, flash, streaming, recording, kubuntu

I have a Kubuntu system which I stream amateur radio sound to via a flash interface. I want to be able to record the sound that the flash player is making at the press of a button. I also need the capability to do (hopefully real-time) spectrum analysis on the sound. I need a program (a firefox add-on would be ideal) that can do this for me.

Comment: Interacting with flash can be difficult.  Your best bet is to use some sort of downloader extnsnion on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try audacity. Have a look at this link -> http://www.seoras.com/2008/05/26/how-to-record-streaming-audio-with-audacity-in-ubuntu-804-hardy-heron/

Comment: I'm using kubuntu so I had to manually install gnome-alsamixer...then, when I looked at the Edit>Sound Card Properties dialog, there was no "Mix" or "Mix Mono" option there.